# What will happen if a poisonous snake bites itself?

Tags: snake

I wonder if in general snakes are immune to their own venom. I would like to know studies or references about times snakes bit themselves and got sick or the contrary.

Comment: Have you tried to [google your question](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=are%20snakes%20immune%20to%20their%20own%20venom%3F)?

Comment: **Homework questions** and **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Comment: This is not a homework question at all, as well after some googling I found 2 sort of answers for this interesting question. Some wrote, The snake will become affected and die. Some other source tells, nothing would happen to it. only a few uses an example, and I found no original experiments reference. https://www.quora.com/Will-a-venomous-snake-die-if-it-bites-itself , http://www.thenakedscientists.com/HTML/questions/question/2276/ , http://www.venomousreptiles.org/forums/Toxinology/23.

Answer (score -1):

> “The conventional wisdom is that they have circulating antibodies in
>   their blood,” says Stephen Mackessy, Ph.D., a Professor of Biological
>   Sciences at the University of Northern Colorado and an expert in
>   venomous snakes. “This would protect them from their own venom, as
>   well of venom from another snake in their own species.”
>
> Hypothetically, if a speckled rattlesnake bit another speckled
>   rattlesnake, the immunity they’ve built from being exposed to low
>   levels of their own venom—kept in glands behind their eyes and
>   secreted when they bite—would protect them from a fatal wound. (Even
>   though the glands are closed, they still contain blood vessels that
>   allow the venom to circulate in their system, causing mild exposure,
>   Mackessy says.) But a speckled rattlesnake that meets up with a cobra
>   might have a different day entirely.

So in the case snake were to bite itself it wouldn't suffer as much from the poison compared to the actual bite it self-inflicted.

Comment: If you're quoting from a source, you should include the source in your answer so others can read the quote in context. Additionally, answers that are completely or almost completely made up of quotes from other sources are generally not good answers. Do research, find several sources, and synthesize a good answer *in your own words*. Make sure you include links and attribution for your sources, however.